How to search substring inside array of string sequelize?
I use sequelize and mysql. Here question. For example I hava column name: DataTypes.JSON . for example i have these data: [ {id:1, name:['mother','adad','asd',...],... }, {id:2, name:['sister','as',..],..}, {id:3, name:['fother',...],...}]  When search q='her' I get id=1 and id=3 data.
Now, how do implement this? name:{[Op.like]: `%${q}%`} or name: {[Op.contains]:[`%${q}%`]}  didnt do. How to do this?
